# How do I paste from powershell so that the encoding is utf-8 into Kate Editor?

Tags: python, powershell, kate

When I copy some multiline text from powershell in windows 10 into Kate, placing it in a multi-line comment in a Python script, and then try to run the same script again; I get an error :
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 228-229: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Have you tried making it a raw string by appending an `r` before the opening quote?

Comment: that worked, thanks. I am transitioning to Windows and getting used to escape and other symbol differences